# How to share data with tenants in abp

Tags: share, multi-tenant, aspnetboilerplate

[image]

1. All tenants can use accounts info.(Head office is a tenant)
2. All accounts can use branch office data
3. Branch office admin only use self data
4. Head office can use all branch office's data

Comment: You have to create Role structure like that

Comment: Direction of arrows make no sense... Is branch office a Tenant?

Comment: @aaron If the tenant can be nested, the branch office can also be a tenant,this image is just one of my ideas, not very standard

Comment: Direction of arrows make no sense... Can you write code?

Comment: If your solution is worth sharing, post it as an answer.

Comment: @clarkwu If your solution is worth sharing, post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In AspNet Boilerplate, tenants are not hierarchical. Theoretically, a tenant's data must be isolated from another tenant's data. If your "tenants" share data with each other so it shouldn't be the tenant. You can use [Organization-Units](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/Organization-Units) for this purpose. Organization units can be used to hierarchically group users and entities.

Comment: Thank you for your reference. I am currently solving this problem. https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/3257